# yeoman generator for laravel5 - issue with composer create-project

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

This question is mainly regarding `yeoman` and `composer create-project` command.
I am developing a [yeoman generator for laravel5](https://github.com/jadjoubran/laravel5-generator) and the issue I'm facing is that to install laravel, I need to run `composer create-project` which creats a new folder called `laravel` inside the root directory.
However, most yeoman packages generate the application in the root directory and all yeoman helpers work assuming that your files are in the root directory as well (for instance npmInstall looks for package.json at the root level).

Composer does not YET support creating a project in the same directory even if it was empty (https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1135).

So I thought that I only have this solution:

- `composer create-project` in a temporary folder then move it's content back to the root folder and delete the temporary folder (node modules recommendations for that?)

Is there any better way? If not, what are some node modules recommendations for moving the content of the folder up to the root directory (I had issues with that to make it cross platform).

I think this question should not be considered as too localized because it might help other yeoman contributors when working with composer.

Answer (score 1):

Now `composer` can create project in current directory if provided empty.

You can follow the detailed discussion over here on `github`.

[create project in same directory](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1135)

With this you wont have to use any `node module` to achieve file transfer.

Comment: Are you sure? I just ran `composer dump-autoload laravel/laravel --prefer-dist` in an empty directory and nothing happened. I already saw this github issue but it's a feature request which wasn't implemented

Comment: Its on one of the alpha branches I think

Comment: Doesn't that mean that I have to wait for over a month until everyone has the most recent version of composer?